# How to load class from another package?

Tags: java

I want to load class from another package(operators is the package name)  .I use this statment  :

```
File operatorFile = new File(operatorPath);
URL operatorFilePath = operatorFile.toURL();          
URL[] operatorFilePaths = new URL[]{operatorFilePath};
ClassLoader operatorsLoader = new URLClassLoader(operatorFilePaths);

Class operatorInterface = operatorsLoader.loadClass("operators.Operator");
```

But at runtime I got this exception  :

[image]

I don't know the way I call Is not correct or other problem Is there with my code  .Can any one help me?

Comment: Why don't you just import the package?

Comment: What is the content of input.txt? What's the value of operatorPath variable? Where is your input.txt located? More info is needed for anyone to understand the problem. Please edit the question with more details.

Comment: My program should read the content of a input (e:\\input.txt).the content is like this 1,2,+  .the application should write the result(3) into other file  .for handling operators I implement one interface (Operator) and 4 class Plus,Minus,Multiply,Divide  .this interface and clasess are in the operators package(D:\oprators.Operator)  .my main program is in the (d:\project\main.FileProcess)  .I should load .class file in operators folder and use them in the app but when I load Operator interface I got this exception  .becouse the app is too long I can't put all part here @Karthik R

Answer (score 1):

```
File operatorFile = new File(operatorPath);
```

This is already wrong. The `File` should be initialized with the directory that is at the top of the package structure. In this case, `operatorPath/..`, assuming `operatorPath` is `"operators"`.

```
URL operatorFilePath = operatorFile.toURL();          
URL[] operatorFilePaths = new URL[]{operatorFilePath};
ClassLoader operatorsLoader = new URLClassLoader(operatorFilePaths);

Class operatorInterface = operatorsLoader.loadClass("operators.Operator");
```

Should work from there.

Comment: I get the operatorPath dynamically and at all operatorPath = d:\operators

Comment: So it should be D:\. If you can't help getting `D:\operators` for some reason, use `File operatorFile = new File(operatorPath).getParent();`. But that would be evidence of something else wrong.